# How to get image titles and source out of a view?

Tags: views

I'm struggling hard to understand how drupal views work. With views i assembled a new front page which takes images from certain content types.

Now i'm writing a module to get the image data out of the view.

My Problem:
where can I find the images: when i write

```
views_get_view('viewsname');
```

I get an array of values but not the images.

How can i get the images out of the view properly?

Comment: this is a pretty in-depth question, but basically, if you do something along the lines of `$view=views_get_view('viewsname');` and then execute the view, $view->result will be an array of objects relating to each row.  There, there "should" be a `$view->result[#]->fid` which is the file id, and is an index into the files table and there you will find the file name and path etc of those images.  You can also look into the `views_get_view_result()` function which is a nice wrapper for getting just results from a view.

Comment: @Jimajamma views_get_view_result() made my day! Holy... Why do you guys know about that function? Thanks a lot. Please submit the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to get Views results to use programmatically, check out the [views_get_view_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) function.  If you do something like:

```
$result=views_get_view_result('viewname');
```

you can then loop through $result, which is an array of objects relating to each row, and the tried and true:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($result, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

will give you all the information you are working with.